# how to set gop size of vp8, video codec, in webrtc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, video-codecs

I'm using the [video conference implementation source code](https://github.com/borjanebbal/webrtc-node-app) using webrtc and nodejs.

I managed to [set VP8 as codec](https://github.com/servo/servo/blob/master/tests/wpt/web-platform-tests/webrtc/RTCRtpTransceiver-setCodecPreferences.html) for the video streaming using setCodecPreferences method as follows:

```
 rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers)
 .......
 const transceiver = rtcPeerConnection .addTransceiver('video');
const capabilities = RTCRtpSender.getCapabilities('video');
const { codecs } = capabilities;
codecs.forEach(codec => {
  if (codec.mimeType.toLowerCase() === 'video/vp8') {
    transceiver.setCodecPreferences([codecs[0]]);
  }
});
```

However, I couldn't find a way to set the GoP length, keyframe rate/s or number of inter-frame in GoP.

Any idea how to configure `RTCPeerConnection` so as to provide this setting?

Comment: Usually GOP can be set via ffmpeg when converting static or live video, but in webRTC I think it's the browser that will check the capabilities of the device...

Comment: Is it a black box in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

The WebRTC JS API doesn't provide a way to set the keyframe interval. WebRTC handles error correction and congestion control for you, and will pick what it thinks the best settings are.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to configure the settings of webrtc video coding to VP8, GoP =10 (3 keyframes for 30 FPS).
I'm trying to evaluate the performance my a prototype with the webrtc's.